# Unknown gap when adding translucant to status bar

Tags: android, android-statusbar

When I am keeping translucent an unexpected gap is appearing under toolbar.

Without applying translucent:
[image: With out applying translucent]

```
private void _setStatusbarTranslucent() {
  // Set the status bar to dark-semi-transparentish
  // here if used _context, getting nullpointer unable to find .getWindow() while accessing camera/ gallery to pick photo
  getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: The first image you tried to post was a dead link. Please [edit] your post to add a proper link if necessary.

Comment: post your layout.xml file too

Comment: Probably you have added paddingTop in your toolbar. Please post toolbar layout as well.